# Angular 6 - Writing a Resolve class for routing that can return more than one dataset

Tags: angular, angular6, angular-routing

I was reading online how to implement the resolve functionality with routes in Angular. However in every example I came across the resolve class that was written only took specific data from one service. e.g:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { APIService } from './api.service';

import { Resolve } from '@angular/router';

@Injectable()
export class APIResolver implements Resolve<any> {
  constructor(private apiService: APIService) {}

  resolve() {
    return this.apiService.getItems();
  }

}
```

In app.routing.ts:

```
const routes: Routes = [
{
  path: 'items/:date',
  component: ItemsComponent,
  resolve: { items: APIResolver }
}
]
```

But what if I want **multiple** resolves? e.g:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { APIService } from './api.service';

import { Resolve } from '@angular/router';

@Injectable()
export class APIResolver implements Resolve<any> {
  constructor(private apiService: APIService) {}

  resolveItems() {
    return this.apiService.getItems();
  }

 resolveCars() {
    return this.apiService.getCars();
  }

 resolvePeople() {
    return this.apiService.getPeople();
  }

}
```

How can I refactor these online examples so I can grab different resolve data?

I apologize if this question sounds a bit ambiguous. I can clarify if needed.

Comment: Basically every example I came across online didn't show me how to return data from more than one service in a single resolve class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, this is not possible. If you want to share logic, you can extend base class like this:

```
export abstract class APIResolve<T> implements Resolve<T> {
  constructor(readonly apiService: APIService) {}

  abstract resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<T>;
}
```

and have multiple resolvers:

```
export class APIItemResolve<T> extends APIResolve<T> {
  resolve(): Observable<T> {
    return this.apiService.getItems();
  }
}

export class APIPeopleResolve<T> extends APIResolve<T> {
  resolve(): Observable<T> {
    return this.apiService.getPeople();
  }
}

export class APICarResolve<T> extends APIResolve<T> {
  resolve(): Observable<T> {
    return this.apiService.getItems();
  }
}
```

and have your routes like this:

```
const routes: Routes = [{
  path: 'items/:date',
  component: ItemsComponent,
  resolve: { 
    items: APIItemResolve,
    peoples: APIPeopleResolve,
    cars: APICarResolve
  }
}]
```

Another way is to make a global resolve, and have your items/peoples/cars saved in a shared Service instead of on the Route data